# Azure queue disappearing

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created an azure queue within the Service Bus and added a few messages to it. I confirmed looking at the message count in the Azure management portal.

At some point (after a few days) the queue is gone (The queue, not the messages). Trying to recreate the queue with the same name results in 'Create failed' and **Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.**

[ I feel stupid asking ]

Has anybody come across this? am I missing a part of the API that deletes the queue after a few days of no use?

Comment: The queue won't be deleted automatically. Are you using the new preview portal (portal.azure.com) or the existing one (manage.windowsazure.com)?  Check your operation logs too for potentially additional information.  If you deleted it, there would be a log of it there.

Comment: I'm using the existing portal. The operation logs shows the Create and Update operations but no delete.

Comment: In that case I think I would recommend contacting support.

Comment: I am having the same issue. What happened here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the portal there is no option to see it but if you use the powershell version there is a parameter for the queue called **AutoDeleteOnIdle**.

Though I had created my queue through the portal and had no choice in the matter I think this parameter got set to something other than infinity. Then when I let it go idle for a few days it got deleted.

Regardless the feedback (error message) on the Azure management portal does not help identify or confirm that this is the issue.